# Trying to install handbrake CLI but I keep getting a gstreamer install issue. Do I have add some additional ppa for this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gstreamer, handbrakecli

I am on an ubuntu-18.04 machine.

Firstly I am adding the handbrake ppa repository in this manner

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
```

Post that I am running the installation using the following commands

```
sudo apt -y update

sudo apt install -y handbrake-gtk handbrake-cli --fix-missing
```

But I constantly keep getting this error

```
Err:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 amd64 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libtag1v5 amd64 1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.2build2 [10.9 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libtwolame0 amd64 0.3.13-3 [46.7 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libv4lconvert0 amd64 1.14.2-1 [76.1 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libv4l-0 amd64 1.14.2-1 [41.7 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libvpx5 amd64 1.7.0-3ubuntu0.18.04.1 [796 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libwavpack1 amd64 5.1.0-2ubuntu1.5 [76.8 kB]
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good amd64 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gstreamer1.0-x amd64 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.3 [74.3 kB]
Err:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good amd64 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Fetched 6,538 kB in 3s (1,908 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-good1.0/libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0_1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-good1.0/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good_1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I checked the file in the repository but it doesn't seem to exist.

How can I update the libgstreamer download link? Do I need to add some other ppa for this?

Comment: Even if this is off-topic here: Ubuntu 18.04 is pretty outdated

Comment: Updating ubuntu is not an option for me at the moment actually.